# Deploying / Handoff a website to client using google domains and github pages

Tags: html, deployment, web-deployment, web-frontend

I am starting a new career as a developer and I am trying to offer my services to shops in my area for free to use as my portfolio. My question is, is it okay to deploy/hand off a website to my client using google domains and GitHub pages? Since it is the cheapest way to deploy a website?
What is the downside of doing so, or should I just suggest using a hosting site such as Hostgator?

I have created a website that is ready to be handed off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

For a simple static website that doesn't have server-side scripting (such as PHP, etc.) GitHub pages are a fine route for deploying your website.

###### *Another factor to take into account would be the GitHub pages limits.*

> - No larger than **1 GB**
> - Bandwith limit of **100 GB** per month
> - Limit of **10** builds per hour *(excluding custom actions workflows)*

###### Other options

- [**AWS**](https://aws.amazon.com/websites/)
- [**Google Cloud**](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-hosting)
- [**Heroku**](https://www.heroku.com/)

> "I am trying to offer my services to shops in my area for free to use as my portfolio."

Based on this alone, I will tell you that GitHub pages are probably the most ideal way to go for a portfolio. If your website is more complex, however, I would go for one of the options I listed above. Since GitHub pages is free and very easy to use, though, I do recommend it. Say your website grows in complexity and you begin to feel you need more wiggle room/flexibility to control how it's hosted, you can always start using something else.

I would personally, at the very least, use GitHub pages as a starting point for a static site.

Comment: So for my client would I recommend her to create a github pages account and help her deploy her website with google domains?

Comment: Yes! I just now understood that you were asking in order to recommend to your client. It's a good option for a portfolio.